# Inserting Checkboxes and Textviews Data into Sever Database

Tags: java, android, json, database

> > ```
> > I am creating a survey app in which i am using checkboxes and textviews 
> >    to show to the questions which i am retrieving from server
> > ```
> >
> > database now i  want to insert the responses of the surveyed person
> >     into the server database .surveyed person can choose more than one
> >     answer. please help me with the java file as i am not able to get the
> >     logic.

My .XML File Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.fortune.axismouseproj.SurveyActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!-- Logo Start-->
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="#232b5a"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
            <!-- Logo Ends -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#c8d6f0">
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Project"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/tvproject" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="330dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tvsurvey" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:id="@+id/chkopt1"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/tvoptone"

                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:id="@+id/chkopt2"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"

                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

                        android:id="@+id/tvopttwo"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:id="@+id/chkopt3"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"

                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

                        android:id="@+id/tvoptthree"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:id="@+id/chkopt4"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"

                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

                        android:id="@+id/tvoptfour"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:id="@+id/btnsubmtnxt"
                    android:background="@drawable/axisnext"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|right"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:id="@+id/btnsumbit"
                    android:background="@drawable/axissubexit"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:id="@+id/btncontinue"
                    android:background="@drawable/axissubcontt"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>


    <RelativeLayout android:src="@drawable/footer1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#232b5b"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#c8d6f0"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/link"
                android:onClick="linkdn"
                android:background="@drawable/axislink"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/twit"
                android:onClick="twiiter"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/axistwitter" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/fb"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:onClick="facebook"

                android:background="@drawable/axisfacebook" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/go"
                android:onClick="insta"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/axisinsta"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/go2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:onClick="youtube"
                android:background="@drawable/axisyoutube"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Axis Mouse © 2016-2017"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

> My Data Retrieval code from server java code

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.renderscript.Sampler;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.json.JSONArray;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class SurveyActivity extends Activity {

    Button submit,conti,nextbtn;
    TextView head,survey,optn1,optn2,optn3,optn4;
    String que,opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4;
    CheckBox checkBox1,checkBox2,checkBox3,checkBox4;
    int surveyno=127;
    int questionno=1;




    public final static String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Message";
    String msg;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsumbit);
        conti = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncontinue);
        head = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvproject);
        nextbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsubmtnxt);
        survey = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvsurvey);

        optn1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvoptone);
        optn2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvopttwo);
        optn3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvoptthree);
        optn4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvoptfour);

        checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkopt1);
        checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkopt2);
        checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkopt3);
        checkBox4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkopt4);




        nextbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                do {
                    new FetchQuestion().execute();
                    questionno++;
                } while (questionno >= 22);









            }
        });

        Typeface type01=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight.ttf");
        head.setTypeface(type01);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Intent fours1 = new Intent(SurveyActivity.this, BeginAction.class);

                startActivity(fours1);
            }

        });

        conti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Intent fours1 = new Intent(SurveyActivity.this, EntrpNxtStart.class);

                startActivity(fours1);
            }

        });

       new FetchQuestion().execute();

    }


    public void linkdn(View view)
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.linkedin.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void facebook(View view)
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void twiiter(View view)
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void insta(View view)
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.instagram.com/"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    class FetchQuestion extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SurveyActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args)
        {



            System.out.println("Doinbackground entered!");

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("questionno",String.valueOf(questionno)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("surveyno",String.valueOf(surveyno)));


            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://localhost/ws/survey.php","POST", params);
            System.out.println("json object made, php should exec now!" + json.toString());

            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    System.out.println(" Details fetched Successfully!");
                    String msg = json.getString("message");
                    System.out.println(" msg " + msg);



                    que = json.getString("question");
                    System.out.println(" que " + que);
                    opt1 = json.getString("option1");
                    System.out.println(" opt1 " + opt1);
                     opt2 = json.getString("option2");
                    System.out.println(" opt2 " + opt2);
                     opt3 = json.getString("option3");
                    System.out.println(" opt3 " + opt3);
                     opt4 = json.getString("option4");
                    System.out.println(" opt4 " + opt4);

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("UnSuccessfull ");
                    msg = json.getString("message");
                    System.out.print(msg);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }



        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url)
        {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            survey.setText(que);
            optn1.setText(opt1);
            optn2.setText(opt2);
            optn3.setText(opt3);
            optn4.setText(opt4);
            checkBox1.setChecked(false);
            checkBox2.setChecked(false);
            checkBox3.setChecked(false);
            checkBox4.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
 }
```

> This is my  Insert.PHP code through which i want to insert data into
>   serverdatabase

```
      <?php
      $response = array();
   $servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "R00t1975#";
$dbname     = "tikox"; 

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, 

$dbname);

    if (!$conn)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


else
{
echo "success";
}

   $userid = isset($_POST['userid']) ? $_POST['userid'] : 

'';

   $surveyno = isset($_POST['surveyno']) ? $_POST

['surveyno'] : '';


  $questionno=isset($_POST['questionno']) ? $_POST

['questionno'] : '';

  $optionno=isset($_POST['optionno']) ? $_POST['optionno']: 

'';



  $query = mysqli_query($connect, "insert into 

answerindividual (userid,surveyno,questionno,optionno) 

values
 ('$userid','$surveyno','$questionno','$optionno') ");



 // check if row inserted or not


 if ($query) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "data successfully inserted.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

 } else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}


mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

> In my database there are four fields userinfo, surveyno, questionno,
>   answerno.  so i want to insert these four values into database. please
>   help me in writing  java code for insertion into the server database